# Unable to add OR in javascript

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

```
    let CheckSchema = {
    title: 'Check Schema',
    type: 'object',
    required: ['id', 'name', 'description', 'wanted'],
    properties: {
        default_show: {
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        default_show:{
            type: null
        }
    }
};
```

and

```
  let CheckSchema = {
        title: 'Check Schema',
        type: 'object',
        required: ['id', 'name', 'description', 'wanted'],
        properties: {
            default_show: {
                type: 'boolean' || null
            },
       }
    };
```

Writing a unit test where checking schema, for the variable default show my datatype can be boolean or null both. However, if I assign boolean it gives error. Hence, please can someone guide me how to write or in this case ?
I have tried to ways which are mentioned above but none of them are working.
Any help would be appreciated.

I am using this in testing with help of Mocha and Chai

Comment: You cannot have two properties with the same name in a single object.

Comment: Are you using a unit test framework/library? I would be they would have documentation about how to do this.

Comment: This depends entirely on what is *reading* this object. It might expect you to write `{type: 'boolean|null'}`, or `{type: ['boolean', null]}` or `{type: { anyOf: ['boolean', null] }` or `{type: 'nullable boolean'}` etc etc. Since you haven't said where it's being used, nobody can tell you.

Comment: @IMSoP I am using Mocha library to do API testing

res.body.forEach((body) => {
                console.log(body);
                expect(body).to.be.jsonSchema(CheckSchema);
            });